# Codename one Textfield in GenericListCellRenderer

Tags: android, codenameone

I am creating a `GenericListCellRenderer` with `Textfield`, i need to edit the `textfield` and replace the values in it, but i didn't get any focus when clicking the `Textfield`. The code i tried was as follows.

```
public Container createGenericRendererContainer() {

        Container c = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        c.setUIID("Container");
        Label name = new Label();
        name.setFocusable(true);
        name.setName("Name");
        c.addComponent(name);

        TextField rollNo = new TextField();
        rollNo.setFocusable(true);
        rollNo.setUIID("TextField");
        rollNo.setName("RollNo");
        rollNo.setEditable(true);
        rollNo.setEnableInputScroll(true);
        rollNo.setEnabled(true);
        c.addComponent(rollNo); 

        return c;
    }
```

Henceforth, I need to get the action listener , that after i edited and press enter the values need to be changed in the database..

Answer (score 2):

ListRenderer are stateless they are only used to display a list item on the list, if you need a Statefull Component don't use a List, use a box layout y Container instead. 
Read this for more info - http://www.codenameone.com/blog/deeper-in-the-renderer

Comment: thanks for your support,  but i need to show the data's as gridview in android with custom textbox, combo box, etc in that gridview with listeners for that.

Comment: So use a GridLayout, TableLayout, Table etc. the same concept applies.